# Finding a curve with a condition on winding numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, plane-curves, winding-number

I want to find a continuous and closed curve $\gamma$ so that the map  $\nu_{\gamma}:\mathbb{C}$\Im$(\gamma)\to \mathbb{Z}$

takes infintely many values. Here $\nu_{\gamma}(a)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ around $a$.

This map exists (by a remark in a textbook). I played around by expressions containing $\sin(1/t)$ to get something which oscillates a lot but can't conclude.

Comment: Ok I found something: $\gamma(t):=t\cdot(t-1)e^{i\sin(\frac{1}{t})}$ seems to work for $t\in[0,1]$. (with $\gamma(0):=0$). Right?

Comment: No, but $\gamma(t) = t(t-1)e^{i/t}$ should work.

Comment: Thanks.Indeed one should throw away this sin in the exponent. I will post the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible answer is $\gamma(t):=t\cdot(t-1)e^{\frac{i}{t}}$ (with $\gamma(0):=0$) for $t\in[0,1]$.